# Aligning two nav lists side-by-side

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is create a store-banner, one half with its contents aligned left, the other half with its contents on the right with space inbetween for resizing. I've attached an image to explain what I'm trying to do.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scss/custom.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="container-fluid flex-nowrap topBanner" role="banner">
        <ul class="nav d-flex">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">1</a>            
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">2</a>            
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">3</a>            
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav d-flex justify-content-end">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">4</a>            
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">5</a>            
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">6</a>            
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
.topBanner {
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
```

[trying to make banner like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2O5a.jpg)

Comment: You said you need space in-between for resizing. What exactly you wish to resize?

Comment: You need to accept any of the suggested answers as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this on `bootstrap`, just add these **two classes** to `container-fluid`:

```
d-flex 
justify-content-between
```

Here:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-between flex-nowrap topBanner" role="banner">
...
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your css:

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
```

May I remind you, when writing CSS inside an HTML document, you must use the `style` tag like so:

```
    <style>
    .topBanner {
        background-color: purple;
        text-align: center;
        width: 50%;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: display: flex did the trick!
I know about styling in html, I just posted what was in my CSS file. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: No worries, since you're using bootstrap s.kuznetsov's answer is more appropriate, adding d-flex and justify-content-between to your classlist is better.

Comment: @FadyBark, Thank you. Your answer is also good.